# Compiling Fsharp with Mono Amazon EC2

Tags: f#, mono, amazon-ec2

When I try to compile F# in a standard way :

`./autogen.sh --prefix=/opt/mono && make  && make install`

it fails with:

`ilwrite: TIME 35.286 (total) 0.000 (delta) - Build String/Blob Address Tables
    make[3]: *** [.libs/proto//4.0/FSharp.Compiler-proto.dll] Killed
    make[3]: *** Deleting file .libs/proto//4.0/FSharp.Compiler-proto.dll
    make[3]: Leaving directory /src/fsharp/src/fsharp/FSharp.Compiler-proto
    make[2]: *** [do-proto] Error 2
    make[2]: Leaving directory /src/fsharp/src/fsharp
    make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: Leaving directory /src/fsharp/src/fsharp
    make: *** [all] Error 2`

I have mono 3.11 from git master installed on my EC2 instance.

Thank you!

Comment: According to this issue https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/fsharp-opensource/xrBxyP0utEA I must increase memory to 2GB from 600 MB( default value for micro instance)

Comment: The `Killed` is the giveaway that the process was killed by a memory shortage

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully compiled F# with m1.small instance and switched back to t1.micro in order to to do this you should:

> ```
> 1 upgrade your currently running instance with larger RAM
>
>     1.1 login to aws console
>
>       1.1.0 navigate to EC2 service
>       1.1.1 choose instances 
>       1.1.1 check instance you want fsharp to be compiled on
>       1.1.2 click actions
>       1.1.3 stop instance
>
>     1.2 change instance type ( m1.small instance with 1.7 GB is enough )
>     1.3 boot your pumped instance (do not forget to reassign elastic IP when instance booted)
>
> 2 compile and install F#  with $ ./autogen.sh --prefix=<YOUR_PREFIX> && make && as sudo make install
> ```

Comment: You should post _how you solved your issue_ in your answer, otherwise it doesn't help anyone in the future.

Comment: For the compile step it is best to run `autogen` and `make` as a regular user and only get root for `make install`